# Append a conditional value to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to check three continuous values in a column and if they are all positive, then create a new column with a string value in the third row. My index is the date index.

I want a new column created in my data frame and want to check in a loop if three consecutive values in a row are positive, then return a string value of 'increasing' or if all three are negative, then return a value of 'decreasing' or if neither, then return 'none'. And this new value should be in the new column and in the row that is the last one of the three values that have been checked.

I have tried below but whatever variation I use, it is not working.

```python
df['num_change'] = df.num.diff()
result = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    
    if np.all(df['num_change'].values[i:i+3]) < 0:
        result.loc[[i+3],'Trend'] =('decreasing')
        
    elif np.all(df['num_change'].values[i:i+3]) > 0:
        result.loc[[i+3],'Trend'] =('increasing')
        
    else:
        result.loc[[i+3],'Trend'] =('none')
        

df["new_col"] = result
```

I am unfortunately not able to insert an image here, I hope someone is patient enough to help me still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with a custom `rolling` without an (explicit) loop

First we define the aggregation (it has to return a numeric value):

```
def trend(s):
    if (s < 0).all():
        return -1
    if (s > 0).all():
        return 1
    return 0
```

Now apply it and map to a label

```
df['trend'] = (df['col'].rolling(3, min_periods = 1)
                        .apply(trend)
                        .map({1:'Increasing', -1:'Decreasing', 0:'none'})
            )
```

output

```
    col trend
0   1   Increasing
1   2   Increasing
2   3   Increasing
3   -4  none
4   -5  none
5   -6  Decreasing
6   7   none
7   8   none
8   9   Increasing
```

Note that we set `min_periods` to 1 here which has the effect of filling the first two rows based on the sub-series of 1 or 2 elements. if you don't want that you can delete the min_periods bit

Comment: thank you very much. I tried and I get everything as Increasing.

Comment: @user18334254 you are not able to reproduce the results in my answer? using `df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [1,2,3,-4,-5,-6,7,8,9]})`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as follows:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : [1,2,3,-4,-5,-6,7,8,9]})

start = 0
end = 3
result = [None] * 2 # because trend will start after the third value

while end <= len(df.col):

    if np.all(df.col[start:end] > 0):
        result.append("Increasing")

    elif np.all(df.col[start:end] < 0):
        result.append("Decreasing")

    else:
        result.append(None)

    start += 1
    end += 1

df["new_col"] = result
```

In this solution, the while-loop runs till the subset of the column in the data frame has at least 3 values, i.e. `end` is less than or equals to the length of `df.col`. Inside it, the first three elements of the column will be checked. If all of them are greater than 0, then the trend "increasing" will be added to the result. If not, then the trend "decreasing" will be added. Otherwise, `None` is added.

The first two elements of the result are `None` because there can be no comparison for the first two elements as the comparison is for the first 3 elements and so on. The `start` and `end` are 0 and 3 respectively, which are incremented by 1 after each iteration. The output is as shown below:

```python
>>> df
   col     new_col
0    1        None
1    2        None
2    3  Increasing
3   -4        None
4   -5        None
5   -6  Decreasing
6    7        None
7    8        None
8    9  Increasing
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried and get a value error. ValueError: Length of values (100) does not match length of index (91460). My dataframe has date index, not sure if that has anything to do with this. Not sure how I can fix this

Comment: Please edit your question and add a [example] so that we can check better why this error is showing.

Comment: I will try, please bear with me. This is driving me crazy because I got this same error some hundreds of times when I try a while loop, even before I reached out for help. My df has a date index and the shape is 100, 11. I dont really get why it keeps giving an error saying the length (100) does not match the length of index (with a significantly higher number than the length of the index as I know). I am unfortunately not able to paste a screen print here, but is there any further information that I can provide with that can help please? I really would appreciate any help in this regards

Comment: I guess you already accepted the other answer? Didn't that solve your problem? The information that can help us figure out the problem is if you paste your code in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71297799/edit) that creates the problem and also the error with full traceback. Only then we can understand what problem you are facing.

Comment: yes, the other answer worked for me, I believe that it is because it is not using while loop. But I would really like to understand why while loop doest work for me, it is very restrictive not to be able to use a while loop on this df anywhere. The code I used is the solution that you provided above and the error with full traceback is unfortunately  too long for me to paste here. But the summary is this 556     if len(data) != len(index): --> 557    raise ValueError(558 "Length of values "
    559 f"({len(data)}) "

ValueError: Length of values (100) does not match length of index (91460)

Comment: I didn't use such line (`if len(data) != len(index)`) in the code above. Maybe you should make a new question and paste the actual code with actual traceback. Unfortunately, I can't really help you like this.

Comment: yes, I dont use this part anywhere, but get it in the error log. I have now created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305699/while-loop-doesnt-work-on-my-pandas-dataframe