# while loop doesnt work on my pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have a pandas dataframe with date index. The shape is 100, 1. Everytime I run a while loop on this, I get an error saying ValueError: Length of values (100) does not match length of index (91460). I tried many ways, giving here one of the ways I tried.

```
start = 0
end = 3
result = [None] * 2 # because trend will start after the third value

while end <= len(mdf6.session_id_count_change):

    if np.all(mdf6.session_id_count_change[start:end] > 0):
        result.append("Increasing")

    elif np.all(mdf6.session_id_count_change[start:end] < 0):
        result.append("Decreasing")

    else:
        result.append(None)

    start += 1
    end += 1

df["Trend"] = result
```

##### Error Log:

> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in require_length_match(data, index) 555 """ 556 if len(data) != len(index): --> 557 raise ValueError( 558 "Length of values " 559 f"({len(data)}) " ValueError: Length of values (100) does not match length of index (91460)

Interestingly, I never use if len(data) != len(index) part that shows up in the error log, in my code in any place. I am new to python, so please bear with me if I am asking an obvious question. It is very retrictive to always avoid a while loop. Any help in this regards is appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: wanted to provide the summary of the error log also please ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in require_length_match(data, index)
    555     """
    556     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 557         raise ValueError(
    558             "Length of values "
    559             f"({len(data)}) "

ValueError: Length of values (100) does not match length of index (91460)

Comment: Why not use a for loop?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to provide a small part of your `mdf6`?

Comment: yes, for loop works and that is how I have been managing so far, but in some cases I feel restricted to have to work around and avoid the usage of while loop. And also I would like to understand why this is happening. I am unfortunately not able to paste a screenprint here, but the index is a simple date index and all columns are just numeric.

Comment: Just quick question, how did your index end up being "91460"?

Comment: I dont know and that is what I am trying to understand. Shape clearly says 100, 11. Could it be because it is date index?

Comment: I am grouping the columns by the date index while creating this df. Could that be the reason

Comment: I found the answer, giving here, maybe it will help someone. It indeed was because I was grouping my df on date. My original data file consisted of 91460 rows and after I grouped it, it had 100 rows. I didnt realize that index would still have a count of 91460, that is why the while loop was not working for me.